# How display: inline is affecting the layout

Tags: css

I have this design problem, where when I resize the browser, the left navigation becomes smaller, someone recommended me to use display inline using media queries.

Below is my code:

```css
@media screen and (min-width:600px) {
  nav {
float: left;
    width: 25%;
  }
  section {
    margin-left: 25%;
    
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width:599px) {
  nav li {
    display: inline;
  }
}

nav{
background-color: navy;
}
section{
  background-color: yellow;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="container elem">
  <span class="label"></span>

  <nav class="elem elem-red">
    <span class="label"></span>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="percent.html">Main</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="percent.html">Contacts</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="percent.html">List</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="percent.html">Hours</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="percent.html">Directions</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="percent.html">Contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <span class="endlabel">/nav</span>
  </nav>

  <section class="elem elem-green">
    <span class="label"></span>
    <p>
      Now when you resize your browser it's even cooler than ever!
    </p>
    <span class="endlabel"></span>
  </section>

  <section class="elem elem-green ipsum">
    <span class="label"></span>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus imperdiet, nulla et dictum interdum, nisi lorem egestas odio, vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec congue eget, auctor vitae massa. Fusce luctus vestibulum augue ut aliquet. Mauris ante ligula, facilisis sed ornare eu, lobortis in odio. Praesent convallis urna a lacus interdum ut hendrerit risus congue. Nunc sagittis dictum nisi, sed ullamcorper ipsum dignissim ac. In at libero sed nunc venenatis imperdiet sed ornare turpis. Donec vitae dui eget tellus gravida venenatis. Integer fringilla congue eros non fermentum. Sed dapibus pulvinar nibh tempor porta. Cras ac leo purus. Mauris quis diam velit.
    </p>
    <span class="endlabel"></span>
  </section>

</div>
```

Without the media query, the nav will be too small to be viewed, so someone advised me to use media query and set display: inline to li. How did display: inline solve this issue? from what I know, display inline will make elements go beside each other, so in fact they should take more space and make my problem worse, but it solved the issue, can someone explain to me why?

Thanks.

Comment: consider using a a flexbox.

Comment: It's not supported in older browsers, I need to support IE8+

Comment: Medi queries aren't supported in those versions either

Comment: I'm not really sure what you are asking... you seem to understand that `li` tags are generally set as `display: list-item;` so I'm not sure what is confusing you.

Comment: I think having `width: 25%;` within your `min-width:600px` media query is what "solved" the issue you are talking about.

Comment: A little feature for IE8 users won't hurt either. You can use modern approaches then add fallbacks if there is a serious readability problem. I don't see why outdated users should beat your app down to a compatibility level.

Comment: Thanks all, I am just learning all of this. I know that when you set an element to display: inline, it will make them appear beside each other, what confuses me is how they are aligned beside each other, and when the browser became smaller, the nav took the whole width? I was expecting if they will be beside each other, and the browser is small, then the right section would overlap or make the nav smaller too, maybe list items would go on top of each other? Why did it take the width?